# reuse result of initialize method from video_player flutter package

Tags: flutter, video-streaming, video-player

Is there option to reuse result of initialize method for video_player package? It takes time for complete - it would be great to cache it (eg. memory level) and reuse it when you back to before used video - and simple use cached data instead of wait for initialize result. I need it for intensive switching between videos.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called cached_video_player which may help resolve your problem. Check it out [here](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_video_player).

Comment: After fast look at the source code of that package - it seems to use cache after initialize method - not for metadata from init method.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you may initialize your video (when played for the first time you cache it on the storage) and then later reuse that same cached video from storage. I understood your question as the given answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about having the screen/page/widget pre-render. That is not currently supported by flutter according to this issue filed on github:

https://github.com/flutter/uxr/issues/6#issuecomment-881918751

> Sure, but this is not very scalable and will quickly turn into a mess. It's much simpler and more flexible to just give MyRoute someway it can cache the next route, and then show that cached route when it needs. ***But flutter doesn't support this as everything needs to be 'on-stage' before it can be initialized.*** In AIR, or Unity, I could simply construct my new page, and it would begin loading data, I could then toss it on stage whenever I want.

PS. You probably already know you can pre-cache the video data/file itself.

Comment: Exactly what I want it's just to call initialize() method for different videos earlier, before use them - to be ready with them later and play fluently different videos later (without waiting for initialize result), so it's kind of pre-cache. Ideally would be have a min part of video buffored too. Do you know how to achieve it? I want to have ready

Comment: [chongman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233382/chongman) can you look at previous comment?